# Submenu is not opening up when provide Scrollbar to the menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

We have a very large menu, so we have provided a scrollbar to that menu. But due to that scrollbar sub-menu are stopped to opening up.

```
   <div id="navbar3" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menus-list">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuItems}}">
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{!item.subMenuItems}}">
                                <li>
                                    <a href='{{item.url}}' menu-url="{{item.url}}" on-click="handleMenuItemClick">{{item.name}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.subMenuItems}}">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{item.name}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
                                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.subMenuItems}}">
                                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{!item.subMenuItems}}">
                                                <li><a href='{{item.url}}' on-click="handleMenuItemClick" menu-url="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>
                                                </li>        
                                            </template>
                                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.subMenuItems}}">
                                                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{item.name}}<span class="caret-right pull-right"></span></a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.subMenuItems}}">
                                                            <li><a href='{{item.url}}' on-click="handleMenuItemClick" menu-url="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a></li>
                                                        </template>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </template>
                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and the CSS code is

```
.scrollable-menu{
                height: auto;
            max-height: 400px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            }
```

The scrollbar is coming up properly but sub-menu stops to open up. Please suggest

Comment: try with `overflow: auto;`

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives an horizontal bar to the menu dropdown itself but could not allow doing anything

Comment: anyone have any thoughts ?

Comment: create to a working example like jsfiddle

Comment: I cannot its a part of polymer component under AWS s3.

Comment: check now maybe work http://jsfiddle.net/qozt42oo/32/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197546/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-mayank).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.scrollable-menu
{
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```